# Randomly iterating through a 2D list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, random

My first attempt to accomplish this resulted in:

```
def rand_Random(self):
    randomRangeI = range(self.gridWidth)
    shuffle(randomRangeI)
    randomRangeJ = range(self.gridHeight)
    shuffle(randomRangeJ)

    for i in randomRangeI:
        for j in randomRangeJ:
            if self.grid[i][j] != 'b':
                print i, j
                self.grid[i][j].colour = self.rand_Land_Picker()
```

Which has the issue of going through one inner list at a time:

[1][1..X]

[2][1..X]

What I'd like to be able to do is iterate through the 2d array entirely at random (with no repeats).

Anyone have any solutions to this problem?

Edit: Thanks for the replies, it appears the way I view 2d arrays in my mind is different to most!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array with all possible pairs of coordinates, shuffle this and iterate through as normal.

```
import random
coords = [(x,y) for x in range(self.gridWidth) for y in range(self.gridHeight)
random.shuffle(coords)
for i,j in coords:
    if self.grid[i][j] != 'b':
        print i, j
        self.grid[i][j].colour = self.rand_Land_Picker()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can consider 2D array as 1D array and randomly iterate through it.

```
def rand_Random(self):
    randomRange = range(self.gridWidth*self.gridHeight)
    shuffle(randomRange)

    for index in randomRange:
        i = index / self.gridWidth
        j = index % self.gridWidth
        if self.grid[i][j] != 'b':
            print i, j
            self.grid[i][j].colour = self.rand_Land_Picker()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
randomRange = range(w*h)
shuffle(randomRange)

for n in randomRange:
    i = n/w
    j = n%w
```

Here `randomRange` basically enumerates all the coordinates from `0` to `w*h-1`.

Even prettier, `i` and `j`, can be found in one statement:

```
i,j = divmod(n, w)
```